# How to pick up child element of specific parent element in Script Assertion?

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertions

I have the following XML example which shows there are multiple occurrences of node 'ProductCode' which fall under both nodes 'PrevHospProduct' and also under 'PrevExtrasProducts'.

```
                <ns2:PrevHospProducts>
                    <ns2:PrevHospProduct>
                       <ns2:ProductCode>D00</ns2:ProductCode>
                       <ns2:ExcessPaid>Yes</ns2:ExcessPaid>
                    </ns2:PrevHospProduct>
                    <ns2:PrevHospProduct>
                       <ns2:ProductCode>900</ns2:ProductCode>
                    </ns2:PrevHospProduct>
                 </ns2:PrevHospProducts>
                 <ns2:PrevExtrasProducts>
                    <ns2:PrevExtraProduct>
                       <ns2:ProductCode>00A</ns2:ProductCode>
                    </ns2:PrevExtraProduct>
                 </ns2:PrevExtrasProducts>
```

For this test I am only interested in the values in 'ProductCode' which are a child of 'PrevHospProduct'. I am not interested in any of the values under 'PrevExtrasProducts'.

I have the following `Groovy Script Assertion in SoapUI` to pick up values in 'ProductCode' but the test is failing as the actual results are also returning 'D00', '900' and '00A' from the examples response. I only want the expected results to pick values 'D00', '900'.

```
def expectedCodes = ['D00','900'] 
def pxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def actualCodes = pxml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'ProductCode' }*.text() as List
assert expectedCodes.sort() == actualCodes.sort()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First need to find the parent node i.e., `PrevHospProduct` and then get the `ProductCode`.

Here is the `script assertion`:

```
def expectedCodes = ['D00','900'] 
def pxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def actualCodes = pxml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'PrevHospProduct'}*.ProductCode*.text() as List
log.info actualCodes
assert expectedCodes.sort() == actualCodes.sort()
```

Comment: Thanks yet again, Rao. Makes perfect sense and looks so easy when you know how!

Comment: @Matt, glad to know that it helped.